# Hibernate three tables many to many

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a database with 3 tables. The main table is `Contract`, and it is joined with pairs of keys from two tables: `Languages` and `Regions`.
each pair is unique, but it is possible that one contract will have the following pair ids:

```
{ (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2) }
```

Today, the three tables are linked via a connecting entity called `ContractLanguages`. It contains a sequence id, and triplets of ids from the three tables.
However, in large enough contracts this causes a serious performance issue, as the hibernate environment creates a staggering amount of objects.
Therefore, we would like to remove this connecting entity, so that Contract will hold some collection of these pairs.

Our proposed solution: create an `@embeddable` class containing the Language and Region id's, and store them in the Contract entity.
The idea behind this is that there is a relatively small number of languages and regions.
We are assuming that hibernate manages a list of such pairs and does not create duplicates, therefore substantially reducing the amount of objects created.

However, we have the following questions:

1. Will this solution work? Will hibernate know to create the correct object?
2. Assuming the solution works (the link is created correctly), will hibernate optimize the object creation to stop creating duplicate objects?
3. If this solution does not work, how do we solve the problem mentioned above without a connecting entity?

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the connecting entity but to employ lazy loading? If I understand you correctly there might be only a limited number of such connection entities per contract - do you need those entities when working with multiple contracts? Besides that, you could use a query to only load the ids from the connection table (e.g. `SELECT connection.region.id, connection.language.id, ... FROM ContractLanguages connection ...`) and manually create the objects you need.

Comment: Look at post on my site, maybe it will be useful: http://itmuslim.org/blog/2014-03-13-629

Comment: @Thomas I do need them all because I hold a lot of contracts in my system at once and each one of them could have exactly the same pairs so what i'm trying to achieve is to hold only one pair entity and all the contracts will have a set of references to this enties. I don't sure I understand your second suggestion, could you please go into some more details?

Answer (score 0):

From your post and comments I assume the following situation, please correct me if I'm wrong:

- You have a limited set of `Languages` + `Regions` combinations (currently modelled as `ContractLanguages` entities)
- You have a huge amount of `Contract` entities
- Each contract can reference multiple `Languages` and `Regions`
- You have problems loading all the contract languages because currently the combination consists of contract + language + region

Based on those assumptions, several possible optimizations come to my mind:

- You could create a  `LanguageRegion` entity which has a unique id and each contract references a set of those. That way you'd get one more table but Hibernate would just create one entity per `LanguageRegion` and load it once per session, even if multiple contracts would reference it. For that to work correctly you should employ lazy loading and maybe load those `LanguageRegion` entities into the first level cache before loading the contracts.
- Alternatively you could just load columns that are needed, i.e. just load parts of an entity. You'd employ lazy loading as well but wouldn't access the contract languages directly but load them in a separate query, e.g. (names are guessed)

  ```
  SELECT c.id, lang.id, lang.name, region.id, region.name FROM Contract c
   JOIN c.contractlangues cl
   JOIN cl.language lang
   JOIN cl.region region
   WHERE c.id in (:contractIds)
  ```

  Then you load the contracts, get their ids, load the language and region details using that query (it returns a `List<Object[]>` with the object array containing the column values as selected. You put those into an appropriate data structure and access them as needed. That way you'd bypass entity creation and just get the data that is needed.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, we already started implementing our @embeddable idea to see if it'll work as we expect (which is actually creating one and only one entity for each possible pair and we expect that all contracts lang + reg sets will hold ref to same entities) but if it will not work we'll go to our plan be wich is what you wrote in your first point (we are trying to avoid DB changes as much as possible). Regarding yoursecond solution, i don't sure i understand where does this secondery query should be placed? is it outside the hibernate table def?